# How do I display results from a sql query via php onto a php page?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

could someone help me out?
I have these 2 files:

1. keywords.php
2. records.php

The keywords.php is like a search page where user submits a query like `keywords.php?keywords=robert`

Now what I want, is to send the value `robert` to records.php and display all records matching the name robert from the `blog_posts` table to the keywords.php page

my keywords.php

```
<?php
$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>    
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>

            <div class="col-lg-12" id="results"></div>
            <div id="loader_image"><img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Loading...please wait</div>
            <div class="margin10"></div>
            <div id="loader_message"></div>
            </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
          var <?php echo $keyword; ?>;
          var busy = false;
          var limit = 15
          var offset = 0;
          function displayRecords(lim, off) {
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              async: false,
              url: "records.php",
              data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
              cache: false,
              beforeSend: function() {
                $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
                $('#loader_image').show();
              },
              success: function(html) {
                $("#results").append(html);
                $('#loader_image').hide();
                if (html == "") {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
                } else {
                  $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading please wait...</button>').show();
                }
                window.busy = false;
              }
            });
          }
          $(document).ready(function() {
            // start to load the first set of data
            if (busy == false) {
              busy = true;
              // start to load the first set of data
              displayRecords(limit, offset);
             }
            $(window).scroll(function() {
              // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
              if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
                busy = true;
                offset = limit + offset;
                // this is optional just to delay the loading of data
                setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);
                // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
                // displayRecords(limit, offset);
              }
            });
          });
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my records.php

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE keyword LIKE '".$keywords."' ORDER BY postid ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<h3>' . $res['keyword'] . '</h3>';
  }
}
?>
```

thanks alot for your help

Comment: Add `&keywords=robert` to the `data:` option, what's the problem?

Comment: What's the problem?  Do you get errors?

Comment: BTW, I recommend you use an object rather than a string as the `data:` option. jQuery will automatically convert it to the query string, with proper encoding.

Comment: @Barmar i get blank page please show it on my code how to would appreciate it alot mate

Comment: The line ```var <?php echo $keyword; ?>;``` will create code like ```var test;``` in the keywords.php file sent to the browser, which will not store the value in a variable. it should be something like ```var keyword='<?php echo $keyword; ?>';```. In your script, you can then reference it using the var name keyword.

Comment: @SloanThrasher could you please do it on my codes mate i have given enough tries but due to less ajax knowledge im not being able to get it to show results

Comment: @EatPeanutButter no error but i get no records either a blank page

Comment: BTW, if you're not using a wildcard in the `LIKE` pattern you should use `=`.

Comment: @Barmar: like will also work without the % if all he needs is a case-insensitive search, but your point is well taken.

Comment: @JohnBukung: Have you tried debugging the records.php file by calling it from the browser with parameters? Make sure it works before trying to debug the ajax part.

Comment: no mate how to do that?

Comment: Just open the web page `http://yourserver.yourdomain.com/records.php?limit=15&offset=0&records=robert`

Comment: its displaying results

Comment: records.php seems to be working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several changes needed in keywords.php. Take a look at the changes below.

```
<?php
$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];
?>      
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>     
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-lg-12" id="results"></div>
    <div id="loader_image"><img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Loading...please wait</div>
    <div class="margin10"></div>
    <div id="loader_message"></div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var keywords = '<?php echo $keywords; ?>';  // Changed
    var busy = false;
    var limit = 15
    var offset = 0;
    // Changed/New
    var data = {
        'limit': limit,
        'offset': offset,
        'keywords': keywords,
    };
    function displayRecords(lim, off) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "records.php",
        data: data, // Changed
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
        },
        success: function(html,textStatus,jqHXR) {
            $("#results").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
                $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show()
            } else {
                $("#loader_message").css('display','none');
                $("#loader_message").html(html);
            }
            window.busy = false;
        },
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // start to load the first set of data
        if (busy == false) {
            busy = true;
            // start to load the first set of data
            displayRecords(limit, offset);
         }
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
                busy = true;
                offset = limit + offset;
                // this is optional just to delay the loading of data
                setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);
                // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
                // displayRecords(limit, offset);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i get this ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: keywords in C:\wamp\www\autoload\index.php on line 2

Comment: ```$keyword``` should have been ```$keywords``` - didn't notice that in your original code. Corrected in my answer

Comment: `$keywords` should be `$_GET['keywords']`

Comment: And then you need to open `keywords.php?keywords=robert`

Comment: My answer doesn't have all of the code from that file. I'll edit it and add the code that was before what I posted.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the whole file instead of just the part that needed changes.

Comment: changed to keywords but still keywords.php is not displaying any result

Comment: yay it fetched mate :)

Comment: @JohnBukung: Have you tested records.php from the browser as suggested?

Comment: really appreciate it i been trying all day now finally it worked but even thought records are over it still says loading please wait

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes i have debug now it display results but then one issue there r just 2 results yet it says loading please wait

Comment: Your success function has only one parameter, Look at the jQuery Ajax function reference. There are three parameters. The first is the status of the call, the second is the data, which is what you want. Also, your records.php file is just returning plain text.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. You are expected to try and debug it yourself, and ask a question about a __specific__ problem you are having with your code. You have some research to do about the jQuery Ajax function, and how to handle the return data.

Comment: please help out on this too mate else il get stuck with this forever :)

Comment: obviously not mate i really appreciate the help u have provided im really greatful

Comment: thanks @Barmar the debugging was something new you taught me i really appreciate it

Comment: If this works for you, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: i have already accepted but there i face issue in database i have 4 records but this keeps getting scrolled and displays unlimited same results

Comment: For that, you need to start a new question.

Comment: @SloanThrasher here it is mate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581955/autoload-results-fetching-same-results-over-and-over