# Autoload results fetching same results over and over

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have implemented the following autoload code. It fetches result from database but it keeps looping the same result over and over.

php code

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$keywords = $_GET['keywords'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE postCat LIKE '".$keywords."' ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<h3>' . $res['postTitle'] . '</h3>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have initialized a static $keyword. Does it ever change? Please alert the keyword in ajax and check.

Comment: @AAT yes it changes just for testing purpose i added static. but  the issue is results keeps looping without a stop

Comment: the keywords is fetching records matching the database column but say if there is a record like "Lorem Ipsum" it diplays on the screen and the more u scrall down the same result keeps showing

Comment: window.busy = false; comment this line and try. I think your problem will be solved

Comment: did  //window.busy = false; still it loads more records when scroll the browser

Comment: you are using setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500); which calls displayRecords() on window scroll

Comment: it is actually not even loading more results in maximize browser but when i make the browser minimize like a mobile size only then the more i scroll the more records shows but in maximize screen nothing working please help me out

Comment: var result_height = $("#results").height();
if($(window).height() > 300px){
 var result_height = result_height + 100;
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > result_height && !busy) {
                busy = true;
                offset = limit + offset;
                setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);
               
            }

Comment: just change given heights according to your desired height of the device. It is adviced to take help from any desiger regarding this bcoz I'm not sure about the condition

Comment: unable to figure out how to set this mate

Comment: it just showing loading please wait

Comment: $('#result').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                busy = true;
                offset = limit + offset;
                setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);
        }
    })

Comment: i updated my code is that how to do it?

Comment: Is it working fine in both window size

Comment: no mate i moved the scroller down it only shows 15 records in browser maximized thought there are more and in database

Comment: in smaller screen also not scrolling anymore

Comment: ok move the data you have defined inside displayRecords()

Comment: nothing working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$keywords = 'events';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>    
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

        <div class="col-lg-12" id="results"></div>
        <div id="loader_image"><img src="loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Loading...please wait</div>
        <div class="margin10"></div>
        <div id="loader_message"></div>
        </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var keywords = '<?php echo $keywords; ?>';  // Changed
    var busy = false;
    var limit = 15;
    var offset = 0;
    function displayRecords(lim, off) {

    // Changed/New
    var data = {
        'limit': lim,
        'offset': off,
        'keywords': keywords,
    };
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "getrecords.php",
        data: data, // Changed
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
            $('#loader_image').show();
        },
        success: function(html,textStatus,jqHXR) {
            $("#results").append(html);
            $('#loader_image').hide();
            if (html == "") {
                $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No records found.</button>').show()
            } else {
                $("#loader_message").css('display','none');
                $("#loader_message").html(html);
            }
            window.busy = false;
        },
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // start to load the first set of data
        if (busy == false) {
            busy = true;
            // start to load the first set of data
            displayRecords(limit, offset);
         }
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            // make sure u give the container id of the data to be loaded in.
            if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {


$('#result').on('scroll', function() { if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) { busy = true; offset = limit + offset; setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500); } })
                // you can remove the above code and can use directly this function
                // displayRecords(limit, offset);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried the events has about 23 records in maximize screen when loads it shows 15 records by default its not scrolling anymore be it maximize or even minimize like a mobile screen :(

Comment: Then there may be some error in your query for fetching result

Comment: hi @AAT i posted my getrecords.php also please check once i cannot seem to figure out what is wrong in it

Comment: "SELECT * FROM blog_posts WHERE postCat LIKE '".$keywords."' ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT ($offset,$limit)";

Comment: still getting no records but if i remove  ORDER BY postID ASC LIMIT ($offset,$limit) then it shows but no scrolling

Comment: if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {busy = true; offset = limit + offset; 
     setTimeout(function() { displayRecords(limit, offset); }, 500);}

Comment: this bit of code is messing LIMIT ($offset,$limit) if i remove records shows but still on scroll no further \records displays\

Comment: Glad it helped u :)

Comment: can u help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621794/need-help-in-conversion-of-this-script-i-tried-but-not-getting-results topic too please :)

Answer (score 0):

this is loading same contents over and over because on each ajax call you are sending same 'data' which is

```
var data = {
        'limit': limit,
        'offset': offset,
        'keywords': keywords,
    };
```

Change the function to use new limit and offset

```
function displayRecords(lim, off) {
    data = {
        'limit': lim,
        'offset': off,
        'keywords': keywords,
    };
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "getrecords.php",
    data: data, // Changed
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#loader_message").html("").hide();
        $('#loader_image').show();
    },
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: still not fetching all records when browser is minimized or even maximized

Comment: total i have 23 records with events but it shows only 16 and not scrolling either

Comment: But did the code I sent fix the issue of same data showing up again and again?

Comment: its not doing anything the moment page loads 16 records shows even if i make browser small nothing is scrolling

Comment: i updated my post and shared the php part please have a look what i did wrong