# pagination to work without jquery within this page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

i have this page called records.php which basically works with ajax pagination but however i wish for it to work without the ajax or any js could someone help out please i am new to it would really be greatfull

i have no idea from where to remove what javascript codes from these codes so that i can do the pagination within this php script, really hoping some expert here could help me out

records.php

```
<?php
    //DB configuration Constants
    define('_HOST_NAME_', 'localhost');
    define('_USER_NAME_', 'root');
    define('_DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('_DATABASE_NAME_', 'data');

    //PDO Database Connection
    try {
        $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host='._HOST_NAME_.';dbname='._DATABASE_NAME_, _USER_NAME_, _DB_PASSWORD);
        $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sqlQuery   = $databaseConnection->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_pagination");
    $count      = $sqlQuery->rowCount();

    $adjacents = 2;
    $records_per_page = 5;

    $page = (int) (isset($_POST['page_id']) ? $_POST['page_id'] : 1);
    $page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
    $start = ($page-1) * $records_per_page;

    $next = $page + 1;    
    $prev = $page - 1;
    $last_page = ceil($count/$records_per_page);
    $second_last = $last_page - 1; 


    $pagination = "";
    if($last_page > 1){
        $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
        if($page > 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(1);'>&laquo; First</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; First</span>";

        if ($page > 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($prev).");'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";   

        if ($last_page < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $last_page; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     

            }
        }
        elseif($last_page > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                for($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($second_last).");'> $second_last</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($last_page).");'>$last_page</a>";   

           }
           elseif($last_page - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "...";
               for($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                       $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                       $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
               $pagination.= "..";
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($second_last).");'>$second_last</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($last_page).");'>$last_page</a>";   
           }
           else
           {
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(1);'>1</a>";
               $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(2);'>2</a>";
               $pagination.= "..";
               for($counter = $last_page - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $last_page; $counter++)
               {
                   if($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                   else
                        $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($counter).");'>$counter</a>";     
               }
           }
        }
        if($page < $counter - 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($next).");'>Next &raquo;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Next &raquo;</span>";

        if($page < $last_page)
            $pagination.= "<a href='javascript:void(0);' onClick='change_page(".($last_page).");'>Last &raquo;</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Last &raquo;</span>";

        $pagination.= "</div>";       
    }


$records    = $databaseConnection->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_pagination LIMIT $start, $records_per_page");
$count      = $records->rowCount();
$HTML='';
if($count > 0)
{
    foreach($records as $row) {
        $HTML.='<div>';
        $HTML.= $row['first_name'];
        $HTML.='</div><br/>';
    }
}
else
{
    $HTML='No Data Found';
}
echo $HTML;
echo $pagination;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the $_POST['page_id'] to $_GET['page_id'] so that the page numbers can be sent through querystring. Then you need to remove the onClick events from all the page links. and for HREF, you have to add the url of the page with page_id as query var and the required page as it value. Something like this:

```
...
...
$page = (int) (isset($_GET['page_id']) ? $_GET['page_id'] : 1);
$page = ($page == 0 ? 1 : $page);
$start = ($page-1) * $records_per_page;

$next = $page + 1;    
$prev = $page - 1;
$last_page = ceil($count/$records_per_page);
$second_last = $last_page - 1; 


$pagination = "";
if($last_page > 1){
    $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
    if($page > 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href='URL_OF_PAGE.php?page=1'  >&laquo; First</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; First</span>";

    if ($page > 1)
        $pagination.= "<a href='URL_OF_PAGE.php?page=<?php echo $prev; ?>'  >&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>&laquo; Previous&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";   

    if ($last_page < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $last_page; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href='URL_OF_PAGE.php?page=<?php echo $counter; ?>'>$counter</a>";     

        }
    }

...
...
```

Comment: there are so many different javascript in it mate hows that to be removed please share more example would help me alot

Comment: Can you replace the section I sent code for fist and let me know if that works? It it does, the others are just about replacing links, which I will help with. But confirm whether or not the solution works.

Comment: i did it mate now how to correct this portion $HTML='';
if($count > 0)
{
    foreach($records as $row) {
  $HTML.='<div>';
        $HTML.= $row['postTitle'];
        $HTML.='</div><br/>';
 }
}
else
{
    $HTML='No Data Found';
}
echo $HTML;
echo $pagination;

Comment: Assuming all your logics to calculate `$start`, `$records_per_page` were correct, I dont think anything needs to change here.

Comment: appreciate it mate for your guidance i managed to make it work now yippie :)

Comment: can u help me with another issue it will be a big help to me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45581955/autoload-results-fetching-same-results-over-and-over